# Pandas / Dask - group by & aggregating a large CSV blows the memory and/or takes quite a while

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm trying a small POC to try to group by & aggregate to reduce data from a large CSV in pandas and Dask, and I'm observing high memory usage and/or slower than I would expect processing times... does anyone have any tips for a python/pandas/dask noob to improve this?

### Background

I have a request to build a file ingestion tool that would:

1. Be able to take in files of a few GBs where each row contains user id and some other info
2. do some transformations
3. reduce the data to `{ user -> [collection of info]}`
4. send batches of this data to our web services

Based on my research, since files are only few GBs, I found that Spark, etc would be overkill, and Pandas/Dask may be a good fit, hence the POC.

### Problem

- Processing a *1GB csv* takes ~1 min for both pandas and Dask, and consumes **1.5GB ram** for pandas and ***9GB ram*** for dask (!!!)
- Processing a *2GB csv* takes ~3 mins and 2.8GB ram for pandas, Dask crashes!

What am I doing wrong here?

- for pandas, since I'm processing the CSV in small chunks, I did not expect the RAM usage to be so high
- for Dask, everything I read online suggested that Dask processes the CSV in blocks indicated by `blocksize`, and as such the ram usage should expect to be `blocksize * size per block`, but I wouldn't expect total to be 9GB when the block size is only 6.4MB.  I don't know why on earth its ram usage skyrockets to ***9GB*** for a *1GB csv* input

(Note: if I don't set the block size dask crashes even on input 1GB)

### My code

I can't share the CSV, but it has 1 integer column followed by 8 text columns. Both `user_id` and `order_id` columns referenced below are text columns.

- 1GB csv has 14000001 lines
- 2GB csv has 28000001 lines
- 5GB csv has 70000001 lines

I generated these csvs with random data, and the `user_id` column I randomly picked from 10 pre-randomly-generated values, so I'd expect the final output to be 10 user ids each with a collection of who knows how many order ids.

#### Pandas

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import pandas as pd
import sys

test_csv_location = '1gb.csv'
chunk_size = 100000
pieces = list()

for chunk in pd.read_csv(test_csv_location, chunksize=chunk_size, delimiter='|', iterator=True):
    df = chunk.groupby('user_id')['order_id'].agg(size= len,list= lambda x: list(x))
    pieces.append(df)
final = pd.concat(pieces).groupby('user_id')['list'].agg(size= len,list=sum)

final.to_csv('pandastest.csv', index=False)
```

#### Dask

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as ddf
import sys

test_csv_location = '1gb.csv'
df = ddf.read_csv(test_csv_location, blocksize=6400000, delimiter='|')

# For each user, reduce to a list of order ids
grouped = df.groupby('user_id')
collection = grouped['order_id'].apply(list, meta=('order_id', 'f8'))

collection.to_csv('./dasktest.csv', single_file=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `groupby` operation is expensive because `dask` will try to shuffle data across workers to check who has which `user_id` values. If `user_id` has a lot of unique values (sounds like it), there is a lot of cross-checks to be done across workers/partitions.

There are at least two ways out of it:

1. set `user_id` as index. This will be expensive during the indexing stage, but subsequent operations will be faster because now dask doesn't have to check each partition for the values of `user_id` it has.

```py
df = df.set_index('user_id')
collection = df.groupby('user_id')['order_id'].apply(list, meta=('order_id', 'f8'))
collection.to_csv('./dasktest.csv', single_file=True)
```

2. if your files have a structure that you know about, e.g. as an extreme example, if `user_id` are somewhat sorted, so that first the csv file contains only `user_id` values that start with 1 (or A, or whatever other symbols are used), then with 2, etc, then you could use that information to form partitions in 'blocks' (loose term) in a way that `groupby` would be needed only within those 'blocks'.

Comment: Hi @SultanOrazbayev - 

Could you help me understand how the indexing would help with the almost exponential rise of memory consumption by dask?

I understand where indexing would come into play in terms of performance.

However, when I see the docs, it says `This realigns the dataset to be sorted by a new column` - if this is happening in memory, it may make the memory consumption even worse no?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if this is worse or not, but in practical terms, yes, there were datasets I worked with where trying to index a dataframe would still cause memory problems due to the amount of data reshuffling for the new partitions.

Comment: And just to add in those cases I would use option 2: do some data restructuring and then use that structure to run dask on smaller groups and/or in a way that would minimize data shuffles.